# Accurate way to get the available free RAM using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the available free RAM on a system using Java (11, but earlier would be good too..)

There are various ways to do this, but none of them are accurate.

As described in various other posts (and on Stackoverflow):

```
/* Returns the maximum amount of memory available to 
   the Java Virtual Machine set by the '-mx' or '-Xmx' flags. */
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();

/* Returns the total memory allocated from the system 
   (which can at most reach the maximum memory value 
   returned by the previous function). */
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();

/* Returns the free memory *within* the total memory 
   returned by the previous function. */
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

But when testing this, I often get `0` returned, so there's another way by using OperatingSystemMXBeans:

```
long memorySize = ((com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)
    ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean()).getTotalPhysicalMemorySize();
long freeMemorySize = ((com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)
    ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean()).getFreePhysicalMemorySize();
```

This works much better, but the values are not accurate, and reports much less available than what there really is.

Is there a standard cross platform way to get total and available RAM in Java? I'm currently stumped..

Answer (score 0):

I use the same thing with OperatingSystemMXBean and it seems to be pretty accurate for me, I have an open source example on github if you want to check it out. It gets available RAM, cpu %, etc

https://github.com/JoeDezzy1/Server-Backend/blob/master/server/system/Resources.java

Answer (score 0):

The `totalMemory` etc methods in `Runtime` are reporting on the memory status of the ***VM***, not your OS. Consider the VM to be like a virtual computer. The OS has given the JVM a bunch of memory and as far as the OS is concerned, all that memory is in use. But to the JVM itself, some of it is free, some of it is in use.

So, if you want to know how much free memory is available at the OS level, those methods are completely useless.

memory reporting is more a shades of gray kind of thing than raw hard numbers. It depends on what 'memory' means. For example:

A system has 4GB RAM, and uses the main disk for swap, which CURRENTLY has 80GB free space. there's 15GB worth of swap occupied, and 2GB of RAM in use.

What is the answer to the question 'how much RAM is free?' Depending on how you define things, 67GB, 2GB, and 0GB are all valid answers. The 67GB answer seems the most useless and yet that is the only truly stable one (in that if the system does some exchanging of swap and physical RAM, even though nothing particularly major happened on the system (maybe you alt+tabbed into another app, or some app woke up in the background), you get a huge swing in free mem if you go with the 2GB measurement.

I'm still oversimplifying because usually a chunk of memory is reserved for higher-auth levelled users, or the kernel itself. Let's say 1GB is reserved for root and the kernel, so that if the system is falling over on load, an admin can still log in and administer the system without being too bothered by all that. Does this count as 'free'? It's literally free memory and yet if you aren't admin you cannot use it.

On mac OS and iphones, at some point an app is notified that it may be killed at any time, the moment the system needs more resources, but it won't do so unless these resources are actually needed: That way, if you have some iPhone app that you just ran, but is currently no longer running (you went back to the springboard or put the phone to sleep), the system does the fast thing either way: If you pick up your phone and start that app, it boots instantly. If you pick up your phone and start something else, the system can force-kill that app, reclaim the memory, and use it for the new app you started.

So.. is that memory 'free' or not? There is no unambiguous way to answer this question.

So on and so forth.

Perhaps think first on why you need this information. Modern computing no longer have a concept of 'free RAM' that is unambiguous and well defined, so, needing to know indicates a problematic model.